# An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\Stra.mdf failed

Tags: c#, sql-server

We are creating a project in our college. When executing we are getting this error. We have registration page where we click on register and get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAtKN.jpg) error

Comment: Post the actual query on this site.

Comment: post the code also.. btw the error is self explanatory.. `name already exist, restricted for security reason, already in use`

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string Constring = ConnectionString.Constring;
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constring);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select usname,pwd from regis where usname='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                 usname = dr["usname"].ToString();
                 pwd = dr["pwd"].ToString();
            }
                        dr.Close();
            con.Close();
            if (textBox1.Text == usname && textBox2.Text == pwd)
            {
                this.Hide();
                UserHome us = new UserHome(textBox1.Text);
                us.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid USername or Password");
            }

        }
```